# Intellij: android-support-v4.jar in included in actionBarSherlock and Project => IllegalArgumentException

Tags: android, jar, intellij-idea

I am currently migrating all my projects from Eclipse to IntelliJ Idea.

When I was using Eclipse, the package was only included in ActionBarSherlock library and when the library was included in my project, everything was automatically added.

With IntelliJ, once the android-support-v4.jar is added to ABS, that does not seems enough, as all my imports are broken.

**Screenshot of ActionBarSherlock (LibABS) imports:**

[image]

Everything seems fine, all the SherlockActivity are fine, but all the stuff related to support is not recognized in my application:

```
java: /home/user/workspace/....
cannot access android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity
class file for android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity not found
```

So, I have to copy manually the jar into a libs folder and include it to my project once again.

**Screenshot of my project imports:**

[image]

The imports are recognized, nut I now get this error:

```
Android Dex: [BeTrains-for-Android] UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
Android Dex: [BeTrains-for-Android] java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Landroid/support/v4/app/ShareCompat$ShareCompatImplJB;
```

Thank a lot for any help.

Comment: Try to remove remove `android-support-v4.jar` from dependencies now. It's already included via `LibABS` dependencies.

Comment: As explained, I get a : java: /home/user/workspace/....
cannot access android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity
class file for android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity not found

Comment: in the first case you don't have `LibABS` dependencies as in the second case.

Comment: First case in a screenshot of LibABS dependencies, second case is a screenshot of my application dependencies

Comment: Try to change `android-support-v4.jar` dependency to scope provided in your project.

Comment: Can you elaborate this answer? I don't understand...

Comment: On the screenshot at the right there is a column names `Scope`. It's now `compile` for every dependency. If you change it to `Provided` then idea won't include it to jar. Check this page [dependencies tab](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/dependencies-tab.html)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21941/discussion-between-waza-be-and-nikita-beloglazov)

Comment: Nikita's solution worked for me.

Comment: after make scope compile to provided...it giving me same reference library problem...any idea?..I mention my prblm here http://stackoverflow.com/q/18427768/2624806 ..please share ur views..thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try to play with dependencies scopes and export flags. Check this page for the description: [dependency tab](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/dependencies-tab.html).

Comment: Waouw, everything is fixed. The issue was that I was using SlidingMenu, so the trick was to include only Slidingmenu in My main project, the Slidingmenu included ABS that needed to be exported, and ABS icluded support jar that also needed to be exported.

Comment: As an FYI, this boils down to needing to set _Export_ within any referenced project, such as ActionBarSherlock in which you want to leverage _that_ projects references, in this case android-support-v4.jar.

Comment: I had the same problem while using Facebook and ActionBarSherlock as modules. I solved this by setting the Scope to Provided in both modules.

Comment: @mparaz I am not getting android.support.v4 in both module option...any idea why?