# ABS + IntelliJ IDEA: unable to start activity

Tags: android, jar, intellij-idea, actionbarsherlock

Following [this tutorial](http://www.ashokgelal.com/2012/12/setting-up-intellij-idea-12-with-maven-actionbarsherlock-roboelectric-androidannotations/) I've added Maven, ABS and AndroidAnnotations to my Android project in IntelliJ IDEA. At first I've struggled with [DEX/cannot access android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14099291/intellij-android-support-v4-jar-in-included-in-actionbarsherlock-and-project) exceptions, and seems to fix it with the following configuration:

[image: app deps]

[image: abs deps]

Right now I'm getting `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity` error.

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="ru.erarta.erarta"
          android:versionCode="1"
          android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <application android:label="@string/app_name"
                 android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock"
                 android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                 android:name=".Erarta">
        <activity android:name=".TabsFragmentActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".DayActivity_" />
        <activity android:name=".CalendarActivity"/>
        <activity android:name=".AboutActivity"/>
        <activity android:name=".EventActivity"/>
        <activity android:name=".PermanentExhibitionActivity"/>
        <activity android:name=".MediaActivity"/>
        <activity android:name=".MapActivity"/>
        <activity android:name=".TypesActivity" android:label="Типы событий"/>
        <!-- uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" /-->
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Main Activity declaration:

```
public class TabsFragmentActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity
        implements TabHost.OnTabChangeListener
```

Logcat output:

```
04-09 16:45:48.614: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(26562): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ru.erarta.erarta/ru.erarta.erarta.TabsFragmentActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: ru.erarta.erarta.CalendarActivity
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1872)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1893)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1054)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4385)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:849)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:607)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
        Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: ru.erarta.erarta.CalendarActivity
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:384)
        at ru.erarta.erarta.TabsFragmentActivity.onTabChanged(TabsFragmentActivity.java:108)
        at ru.erarta.erarta.TabsFragmentActivity.initialiseTabHost(TabsFragmentActivity.java:73)
        at ru.erarta.erarta.TabsFragmentActivity.onCreate(TabsFragmentActivity.java:51)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1072)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1836)
        ... 11 more
```

I've decompiled APK with `apktool` here is `$ find . | grep support`:

```
./smali/android/support
./smali/android/support/v4
./smali/android/support/v4/app
./smali/android/support/v4/app/Watson$OnCreateOptionsMenuListener.smali
./smali/android/support/v4/app/Watson$OnOptionsItemSelectedListener.smali
./smali/android/support/v4/app/Watson$OnPrepareOptionsMenuListener.smali
./smali/android/support/v4/app/Watson.smali
./smali/com/actionbarsherlock/internal/view/View_HasStateListenerSupport.smali
```

Here is code around TabsFragmentActivity.java:108:

```
public void onTabChanged(String tag) {
    TabInfo newTab = this.mapTabInfo.get(tag);
    if (mLastTab != newTab) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = this.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        if (mLastTab != null) {
            if (mLastTab.fragment != null) {
                ft.detach(mLastTab.fragment);
            }
        }
        if (newTab != null) {
            if (newTab.fragment == null) {
                newTab.fragment = Fragment.instantiate(this,
                        newTab.clss.getName(), newTab.args);
                ft.add(R.id.realtabcontent, newTab.fragment, newTab.tag);
            } else {
                ft.attach(newTab.fragment);
            }
        }

        mLastTab = newTab;
        ft.commit();
        this.getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us your `CalendarActivity` and line 108 of `TabsFragmentActivity`

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, I've added line 108 procedure to the question and here is [`CalendarActivity`](https://gist.github.com/cfr/5345763)

Comment: ehm, line 108 actually is `newTab.fragment = Fragment.instantiate(this, newTab.clss.getName(), newTab.args);`

Comment: Here is [full tree](http://ix.io/566) of apktool unpacking --- there is no `.smali` files related to support-v4 lib, does it means it jar is not packed into the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is pretty basic: I was trying to put `FragmentActivity` instead of `Fragment` in tab. [Here is](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/actionbarsherlock/HuZEQG1mk08) related discussion in ABS group.