# Add a module dependency which contains other dependencies

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I'm using IntelliJ 12 . 
I have a `Module A` which has module dependencies to github projects. I added to my main `Module B` a dependency to `Module A`.

`Module A` depends on `module1`, `module2`, `module3` , ...

`Module B` depends on `Module A`


But `Module B` doesn't find any reference to `module1`, `module2`, ... That's how I declared it in Eclipse ( "add library project" ) and it works.

Now if I add to `Module B` the `module1`, `module2` ... it will affect `Module B` project.properties messing up with Eclipse. I can get this from Eclipse

> Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define  
> Module
>   B] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple
>   dex files

What's the right way in IntelliJ to add dependency from a module which itself contains several dependencies ?

**EDIT**
I followed CrazyCoder's instructions. Then IntelliJ is telling

> Android Dex: [Module B] UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION: Android Dex:
>   [Module B] java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added:
>   Landroid/support/v4/app/ShareCompat$ShareCompatImplJB; Android Dex:
>   [Module B] at
>   com.android.dx.dex.file.ClassDefsSection.add(ClassDefsSection.java:123)
>   Android Dex: [Module B] at
>   com.android.dx.dex.file.DexFile.add(DexFile.java:163)

Some of `module1`, `module2` ... contain android-support-v4.jar in libs folder. The jar dependency is added but not exported.
Only `Module A` has its library (containing all the jar in libs folder) exported

Comment: Enable the **Export** checkbox for the dependencies in module A that you want to be available to module B.

Comment: Thanks CrazyCoder , where do you find this checkbox in the UI ? Still no clue after reading this http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/dependencies-tab.html

Comment: Does [this screenshot](http://img27.imageshack.us/img27/4731/20130424131434.png) help?

Comment: Avoid multiple dependencies, `android-support-v4.jar` should present only once in one of the modules and available to other modules via the dependencies.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Thanks to CrazyCoder, I exported all the dependencies from `Module A`

[image]

For the multiple dependencies of the same .jar . I just set android-support-v4.jar as `Project Library`. After reading [Intellij: android-support-v4.jar in included in actionBarSherlock and Project => IllegalArgumentException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14099291/intellij-android-support-v4-jar-in-included-in-actionbarsherlock-and-project) . I changed the scope from `Compile` to `Provided` of android-support-v4 in all Modules that references it.

Comment: This was driving me nuts! If I could upvote your answer more than once I would! Thanks.

Comment: Changing the scope from "Compile" to "Provided" is a very importante step!
Thanks for sharing @raychenon

Comment: Looking back at this old post, I am glad Gradle handles the dependencies now :)