# Javah and Eclipse missing class files (android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-ndk, javah

I want to generate headers using javah but when i do i get an error:

```
Error: cannot access android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity
  class file for android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity not found
```

I created new External Tool with this parameters:

- **Location:** D:\Android\jdk1.7.0_51\bin\javah.exe
- **Working Directory:** D:\Android\workspace\MyApp\bin\
- **Arguments:** -d D:\Android\workspace\MyApp\jni -classpath D:\Android\workspace\MyApp\bin\classes;D:\Android\workspace\appcompat_v7\libs\android-support-v7-appcompat.jar com.example.myapp.MainActivity

I use last version of Android SDK and NDK as last version of Java.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Try adding `android-support-v4.jar` to your classpath arguments; not sure where it is, just doing Google searches.

Comment: Yep, that solved it, thanks. But v7 should already have v4 support

Comment: @StarsSky [javah](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javah.html) != java

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved by adding `android-support-v4.jar` to your javah class path arguments.

I am not an Android developer, this was a result of [hunting around on Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=cannot%20access%20android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity) (for example, information derived indirectly from the answer to [IntelliJ 12 + ActionBarSherlock setttings: Could not find class 'android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16403314/intellij-12-actionbarsherlock-setttings-could-not-find-class-android-support)). I do not know why this is required in addition to standard v7 jars, and I am posting this answer as community wiki in hopes that somebody with more experience can edit it to add some more information in the future.