# Outdated Kotlin Runtime

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I got this message when i wanted to update the kotlin runtime:

Your version of Kotlin runtime in 'kotlin-stdlib-1.1.2-4' library is 1.1.2-4, while plugin version is 1.1.3-release-Studio 3.0-2.
Runtime library should be updated to avoid compatibility problems.

Some of codes segment which is exist in the file build.gradle

ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.2-4' 
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha8'

Can anyone help me to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: What exactly about the message don't you understand? The message seems pretty clear.

Comment: How i can update the kotlin runtime? and i don't which kotlin version is compatible with the gradle version 3.0.0.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Outdated Kotlin Runtime warning (Kotlin plugin 1.1.2-release-Studio2.3-3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43928118/outdated-kotlin-runtime-warning-kotlin-plugin-1-1-2-release-studio2-3-3)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Go to your `build.gradle` file. 
Change

```
ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.2-4'
```

to

```
ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.3-2'
```

For future references, visit this [link](https://bintray.com/bintray/jcenter/org.jetbrains.kotlin%3Akotlin-gradle-plugin) to see the latest update and update it accordingly in your `build.gradle` file.

Comment: I will try to change it to this version and restart the android studio, hopefully this notification about kotlin outdated runtime is solved.                                                                                                       THANKS

Comment: If it solves your problem, don't forget to accept the answer. ))

Comment: I don't have that defined anywhere in my project, still getting that warning though :S

Comment: I can say that the problem can be in plugin for Android Studio. Open Android Studio -> File -> Settings -> Plugins -> Browse repositories... -> Find Kotlin Repo -> Push Update button at the top right corner of the window.