# Android studio 3: Outdated Kotlin Runtime

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

I don't use kotlin in my current a project, but always showing following warning:

[image: Step1]

When I click to "Update runtime" will be show following popup:

[image: Step2]

And here dependencies who i used:

[image: Step3]

Anybody know how to solve this google trick?

**Edit

This is bug of Android studio, because i don't using kotlin. If any body will be any idiom how to fix it can add extra answer to this a question

Comment: Your other projects have used Kotlin?

Comment: By the way, you can click "Ignore"... Is there an error otherwise? That is just a warning... "Gradle sync finished" looks like nothing bad is happening

Comment: @cricket_007 yes, i have not errors with kotlin problem, project builds is successfully, I want know how to update kotlin runtime if i don't use just in this project

Comment: You could define a useless `ext.kotlin-version` attribute, like the other answers for this message are saying

Comment: yes, i can, will be try now

Comment: I added ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.60' to build script but not helped

Comment: do not post code as screenshot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Outdated Kotlin Runtime warning (Kotlin plugin 1.1.2-release-Studio2.3-3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43928118/outdated-kotlin-runtime-warning-kotlin-plugin-1-1-2-release-studio2-3-3)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add this into your `build.gradle (Project)`

```
buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.60'
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
}
```

And this code into your `build.gradle (Module)`

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

dependencies {
implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
}
```

This will update your Kotlin version. You can find more in [Kotlin Targeting Android](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-gradle.html)

Comment: One more comment : re-install Android Studio and Kotlin plugin

Comment: Re-installing Kotlin plugin will be enough.

Comment: To re-install Kotlin plugin, Android Studio -> Preferences -> Plugins, uncheck Kotlin, then recheck it. Then click on restart Android Studio button. This solved my problem