# Android Studio 0.2.2 + ActionBarSherlock settings: Could not find class 'android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity'

Tags: android, android-studio, ide, actionbarsherlock, fragmenttransaction

similar problem mention [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16403314/2624806).
I set android-support-v4 to compiler also but still I am getting problem related to reference library.

[image]

How can solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you requested my settings to be shared, I here post my project settings window.
Hope that you can help.

**1. ActionBarSherlock project.**

Note that only android-support-v4 is checked to be exported.

[image: ActionBarSherlock]

**2. My personal project settings windows.**

Nothing special but only ActionBarSherlock project is referenced.
[image]

Comment: I added reference lib support for ActionBarSherlock project and set scope to compile ..it give me junit related issue...i deleted test cases(not'n good idea) of library project..n it work for me..thanks for ur response.

Comment: Glad to solve the problem. yeah me also had problem with jUnit in ABS.